# Powershell string search with wildcard and backslashes

Tags: powershell, search, wildcard

In a file I have the following string I need to search for multiple times:

```
e:\\installroot\\Development2_14.07.21.000\\
```

The first part of the string should always be constant: `"e:\\installroot\\"`

But the second part of the string will change (never be the same), and I also need to search for this string and replace it with a new value: `"Development2_14.07.21.000"`

Here is an example of the file (reg file) that I'm trying to update:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CompanyName\Services]
"Proc"="w:\\installroot\\Development2_14.07.21.000\\debug\\job.dll,JobServiceThread,interval;30;w:\\installroot\\Development2_14.07.21.000\\debug\\proc.exe deltasets=TEMP"
"Order"="W:\\installroot\\Development2_14.07.18.000\\debug\\order.dll,OrderThread,"
"GBatch"="NULL,ServiceThread,daily;01:10;W:\\installroot\\Development2_14.07.18.000\\debug\\file.exe"
```

I'm not sure if a wildcard or regex search/replace would work best here, and therefore could use some input here as to what might be the best approach. NOTE the double-backslashes.

Also, instead of updating the reg file and doing a reg import, I'd prefer to update the registry directly, so hopefully that can be done here in PowerShell.

Also NOTE: I won't always be able to use the term "Development2_" in my search scenario. At times it might be "Development_", or "Test_" or "Release_", or whatever in that path. Just something that needs to be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert Generic Find-and-Replace script Here:

```
(gc C:\temp.txt) | % { 
    if($_ -like "*installroot*") {
        $_ -replace 'installroot\\.+?\\',"installroot\Development_14.07.21.111\"
    }
    else {
        $_
    }
 }| set-content C:\Temp.txt
```

And yes, you're right, it would be easier to just make these changes to the registry directly with powershell. You should try it, let us know how it goes...

Comment: Thanks for the input. I won't always be able to use the term "Development" in my scenario. At times it might be "Development2", or "Test" or "Release", or whatever. Just something that needs to be considered.

Comment: I modified the -replace string a bit to help meet my criteria and got your solution to work: `$_ -replace 'installroot\\.+?\\',"installroot\\$buildnum\"` Of course this is only doing a S/R on the reg file. Need to try it on the registry directly. Thanks Cole!

Comment: yes, exactly how I just updated my answer, see, your way ahead of me :D, registry won't be much different, once you figure how to traverse it and get / set values

Answer (score 1):

Why is Select-String not operating as you require?

In:

`(cat .\temp.txt | Select-String -Pattern "installroot") | % { $_.ToString() | % { $_ -replace $_.Substring(17), "Some new content" } }`

Out:

`e:\\installroot\\Some new content\`

Comment: Hmm...not quite working. The file I'm actually doing the search/replace on is a reg file, and then once done I do a reg import filename.reg to update the registry with the changes. Ideally I'd prefer to update the registry directly by updating all the string values under: [HKLM\SOFTWARE\CompanyName\Services]

Comment: Any error codes? Can you share a wider part of file or ideally a whole file? Not sure what has gone wrong since the script worked for the conditions you initially gave?

Comment: Here is an example of the reg file contents I'm trying to update: `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CompanyName\Services]
"Proc"="w:\\installroot\\Development2_14.07.21.000\\debug\\job.dll,JobServiceThread,interval;30;w:\\installroot\\Development2_14.07.21.000\\debug\\proc.exe deltasets=TEMP"
"Order"="W:\\installroot\\Development2_14.07.18.000\\debug\\order.dll,OrderThread,"
"GBatch"="NULL,ServiceThread,daily;01:10;W:\\installroot\\Development2_14.07.18.000\\debug\\file.exe"`

Comment: And here is the PS code: `(cat d:\temp\temp.reg | Select-String -Pattern "installroot") | % { $_.ToString() | % { $_ -replace $_.Substring(17), "BUILDNUM" } } | set-content d:\temp\temp.reg`

Comment: OK, this moves the challenge to a far new level. I'm not sure I'll be able to come with solution quickly. In the meantime, please try to edit your original question so that it covers these details as they are important.